# pip install fuse-python: pkg-config unavailable, build terminated

Tags: python, macos, pip, fuse

I am trying to install python bindings for osx fuse with pip on osx 10.8.5. I am running python 2.7.2. I am running fuse 2.6.1. When I run the pip install command I get this error. I do not know how to debug it.

```
akh$ pip install fuse-python
Downloading/unpacking fuse-python
  Downloading fuse-python-0.2.tar.gz (53kB): 53kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package fuse-python
    pkg-config unavailable, build terminated
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    pkg-config unavailable, build terminated

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hx/xb3zxftx6vlbd8nh1dbs6rc80000gn/T/pip_build_akh/fuse-python
Storing complete log in /Users/akh/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Here is the tail of the log:

```
My Machine:Json akh$ tail 10 /Users/akh/Library/Logs/pip.log 
tail: 10: No such file or directory
==> /Users/akh/Library/Logs/pip.log <==
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1134, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 259, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hx/xb3zxftx6vlbd8nh1dbs6rc80000gn/T/pip_build_abramhandler/fuse-python
```

Comment: Have you installed Xcode and its command line tools?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I installed xcode, installed command line tools and then uninstalled x code

Answer (score 2):

I needed pck-config. Installing pck-config fixed the problem. These commands lead to a successful install.

```
brew install pkg-config
sudo pip install fuse-python
```